# Скрыть содержимое div с помощью сss

Tags: css

Всем привет. Есть див с содержимым интересует как его скрыть с помощью сss по клику на кнопку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CSS можно танцевать только за счет чекбоксов и радио-кнопок. Есть селектор `.elem:checked`, позволяющий находить отмеченные чекбоксы. А еще есть HTML-тег `<label>`, который умеет при клике переключать эти чекбоксы (и может имитировать кнопку).

Плюс, CSS-селектор `.bubu ~ .kuku` находит все элементы с классом .kuku, которые находятся где-то ниже в коде от .bubu, при этом они оба должны быть одинакового "уровня" - т.е. не обернуты в дополнительные теги.

Поэтому пример: При клике на label, невидимый чекбокс отмечается, 

а к его отметке привязан стиль для .bubu `#hide:checked ~ .bubu {display: none;}`

( *i* ) через `.` тыкают на класс, а через `#` - id.

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 150px; padding: 2px;
  font-size: 20px; text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  cursor: pointer; user-select: none;
}

#hide {display: none;}
#hide:checked ~ .bubu {display: none;}

.bubu {margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<label for="hide" class="btn">Кнопка</label>

<input id="hide" type="checkbox">
<div class="bubu">Какое-то содержание...</div>
<div class="bubu">Другое содержание...</div>
```

Но такой код при повторном клике - опять покажет текст. Если нужно его убрать навсегда, можно использовать одну радио-кнопку:

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px; padding: 2px;
  font-size: 20px; text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  cursor: pointer; user-select: none;
}

/* #hide-1, #hide-2 {display: none;} */

#hide-1:checked ~ .bubu {display: none;}
#hide-2:checked ~ .bubu {display: none;}

.bubu {margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<label for="hide-1" class="btn">Кнопка-1</label>
<label for="hide-2" class="btn">Кнопка-2</label>

<div>
  <input id="hide-1" type="radio" name="hide-1">
  <div class="bubu">Какое-то содержание...1111</div>
  <div class="bubu">Другое содержание...1111</div>
</div>

<div>
  <input id="hide-2" type="radio" name="hide-2">
  <div class="bubu">Какое-то содержание...2222</div>
  <div class="bubu">Другое содержание...2222</div>
</div>
```

Невидимость радио убрал, чтобы было видно, что происходит. В этом случае завернул их в дополнительные блоки, чтобы `#hide1 ~ .bubu` не цеплял блоки, предназначенные для hide-2

---

За счет `~` разметка может быть чуть более свободной. 

Если блок с "содержимым" точно один, и точно потом не забудете, почему там стоит этот чекбокс, можно использовать селектор `.bubu + .kuku`, который выделяет .kuku, находящийся непосредственно после .bubu, и между ними больше ничего не должно стоять:

```css
#hide {display: none;}
#hide:checked + .bubu {display: none;}

.bubu {margin: 10px;}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 150px; padding: 2px;
  font-size: 20px; text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  cursor: pointer; user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="hide" class="btn">Кнопка</label>

<input id="hide" type="checkbox">
<div class="bubu">Какое-то содержание...</div>

<div class="bubu">А это уже не скроется...</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое